# Robots on board the ISS: Expectations and results?

Tags: iss

In the continuation of "[are there any humanoid robots on board the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/are-there-any-humanoid-robots-on-board-the-iss?rq=1)"...

Do we have more information, further than [marketing](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/space/10529852/Kirobo-robot-has-first-space-chat-on-board-ISS.html), e.g:

- Do we have firm **plans** for **cognitive** robots on board the ISS?
- If we have plans, what are the **expectations**?
- So far, **what robots have been tested / used for** in the ISS?
- What are the current **results / benefits**?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The most useful robots onboard currently are the SSRMS and JEMRMS, both are teleoperated robotic systems.

The JEMRMS (Japanese Experiment Module Remote Manipulator system) is

> a 10m long robotic arm, mounted at the port cone of the PM, intended
>   to service the EF and to move equipment from and to the ELM. The RMS
>   control console was launched while inside the ELM-PS. The main arm was
>   launched with the PM. The "Small Fine Arm", is 2m long and attaches to
>   the end effector of the main arm, was launched aboard.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibo_%28ISS_module%29))  Acronyms: PM - Pressurized Module, EF - Exposed Facility, ELM - External Logistics Module

The SSRMS (Space Station Remote Manipulator System)

> Launched on STS-100 in April 2001, this second generation Canadarm is
>   a larger, more advanced version of the space shuttle's original
>   Canadarm. Canadarm2 is 17.6 m (58 ft) when fully extended and has
>   seven motorized joints. It has a mass of 1,800 kg (4,000 lb) and a
>   diameter of 35 cm (14 in). The arm is capable of handling large
>   payloads of up to 116,000 kg (256,000 lb) and was able to assist with
>   docking the space shuttle. Officially known as the Space Station
>   Remote Manipulator System (SSRMS), it is self-relocatable and can move
>   end-over-end to reach many parts of the Space Station in an
>   inchworm-like movement. In this movement, it is limited only by the
>   number of Power Data Grapple Fixtures (PDGFs) on the station. PDGFs
>   located around the station provide power, data and video to the arm
>   through its Latching End Effectors (LEEs). The arm can also travel the
>   entire length of the space station truss using the Mobile Base System.
>
> Most of the time the arm operators see what they are doing by looking
>   at the three Robotic Work Station (RWS) LCD screens. The MSS has two
>   RWS units: one located in the Destiny module (US Lab module) and the
>   other in the Cupola. Only one RWS controls the MSS at a time. The RWS
>   has two sets of control joysticks: one Rotational Hand Controller
>   (RHC) and one Translational Hand Controller (THC). In additional to
>   this is the Display and Control Panel (DCP) and the Portable Computer
>   System (PCS) laptop.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Servicing_System)

Note that no one involved with the SSRMS *ever* refers to it as the Canadarm.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested on cognitive robots rather than the robotic arms. I'll add this element in the question. Your answer is appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: I thought so, but since all the other robotic equipment is strictly experimental, I thought it would be good to at least mention the operational robotics gear.  Perhaps someone who is familiar with the experimental gear can edit or replace what I wrote.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's possible that since your post, Chris Hadfield might have used that nom-de-boom once or twice in an outreach video downlink to his fellow SSRMSians. ;)

Comment: That would be PR.