# How many robots have been at, in, or on the ISS?

Tags: robotic-missions, robotics, aerobot, robotic-arm

Part of the problem is that the definition of robot can be a bit of a slippery slope. Can a spacecraft which has autonomous docking capability be considered a potential robot for example? If you are counting spacecraft, assume one of each kind you are counting is present.

And for this question, a robot does not necessarily need to be autonomous. A spacecraft remotely controlled could be a robot for this question for example. If something is officially robotic, it's a robot.

To further narrow it down, for this question a robot should have some mobility. It should be able to move or orient itself — or at least appendages or parts of itself — without someone (a human) grabbing it and moving it, or d be able to move/orient another substantial object in a complex manner.

Science packages may have little gizmos that feed animals or mix, aliquot, or titrate liquids for example. If you know of some cool or prominent ones, count 'em!

Routine movement like pumps to periodically circulate fluids (e.g. water) or fans or magnetic pickups on old-style hard drives would not be robots for example.

---

And don't forget to count the ones that just plain look like robots!

[image]

Comment: Highly relevant: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/are-there-any-humanoid-robots-on-board-the-iss?rq=1

Comment: Some items here may be relevant: http://www.spacestationresearch.com/facilities-hardware/iss-hardware/

Comment: The big list: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/experiments_hardware.html

Comment: @called2voyage nice!

Comment: Also highly relevant: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/robots-on-board-the-iss-expectations-and-results/6637#6637

Answer (score 3):

Here is a selection of robotic equipment that has been at/in/on the ISS, feel free to add additional references:

- [Cell Biology Experiment Facility (CBEF)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/CBEF.html) can autonomously control a centrifuge, among other functions. While holding at 1G may fall under the "routine movement" section of the question, the centrifuge can alternate between a range of gees, which seems to qualify it to be a robot under the constraints of the question (dynamic movement of an appendage).
- [Avian Development Facility (ADF)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/380.html)
- [Microscope Observation System](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/269.html)
- [Aquatic Habitat (AQH)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/221.html) has "[a]n automatic feeding system [that] can be programmed to support different feeding sequences as needed."
- [Commercial Generic Bioprocessing Apparatus (CGBA)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/338.html) may be fitted with Gas Exchange - Group Activation Packs (GE-GAPs), "a piece of hardware similar to a small test tube", which can be programmed or remotely operated to "activate, mix, grow, and terminate biological experiments."
- [Advanced Space Experiment Processor (ADSEP)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/378.html)
- [Microgravity Science Glovebox (MSG)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/350.html) "allow[s] experiments to be controlled from the ground."
- [Dynamically Controlled Protein Crystal Growth (DCPCG) apparatus](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/187.html)
- [Light Microscopy Module (LMM)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/541.html) "[can begin] the remote operation of the microscope, and processing of the samples" "[a]fter the sample has been positioned [by ISS crew]".
- [Microencapsulation Electrostatic Processing System (MEPS)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/277.html)
- [Advanced Astroculture (ADVASC)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/185.html)
- [European Modular Cultivation System (EMCS)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/345.html)
- [Plant Generic Bioprocessing Apparatus (PGBA)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/273.html)
- [Advanced Plant Habitat Facility (PHF)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/2302.html)
- [Robot Experiment on JEM (REXJ)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/121.html)
- [Mobile Servicing System (MSS) / Canadarm2](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/structure/elements/mss.html)
- [Japanese Experiment Module Remote Manipulator System (JEMRMS)](http://iss.jaxa.jp/en/kibo/about/kibo/rms/)
- [NanoRocks](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1358.html)
- [Stratospheric Aerosol and Gas Experiment III (SAGE III)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1004.html)
- [Sun Monitoring on the External Payload Facility of Columbus - SOLar Auto-Calibrating EUV/UV Spectrophotometers (Solar-SOLACES)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/407.html)
- [Optical Fiber Production in Microgravity (OFPIM)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/2421.html)
- [NanoRacks-ArduSat-1](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1210.html)
- [Synchronized Position Hold, Engage, Reorient, Experimental Satellites-Zero-Robotics (SPHERES-Zero-Robotics)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/690.html)

Honorable Mention:

- [Buzz Lightyear](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/853.html) fails the robot test because he was neither autonomous nor remote-controlled.

Comment: I've added everything "robotic" I could find from the Animal Biology and Cellular Biology sections on "The big list" that I linked above, though I certainly wouldn't mind others double-checking. I will proceed with the other sections later, though others are free to peruse them and add from them as well.

Comment: I was a little nervous at first (it's a pretty big starting list, the "[big list](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22038/#comment61997_22038)" as you mention) but you've face the slippery slope head-on and come up with a really nice selection. Clicking through to the individual experiments selected so far shows descriptions of what I think most people here would agree to be clear examples of *robotic experiments*. I had no idea that use of these kinds of experiments, either autonomous or via direct control by Earth scientists, was so extensive!

Comment: I've now finished with the Macromolecular Crystal Growth section.

Comment: Microbiology and Microencapsulation sections complete.

Comment: you're doing great here! I wonder if some eventual categories are possible? I'd call them *science robots*, *round robots*, *"robot-shaped" robots*, and *systemic/infrastructue robots* which are not really good names for categories, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: @uhoh The trouble with the categories of "Experiment facilitation equipment" and "Anthropomorphic robots" (which is what I think you're getting at with "science robots" and "robot-shaped robots") is that they are overlapping categories. I think it would be better if we just listed them and stated in brief what types of robots there were afterward. However, I don't think we should do any such processing until at least the big list is complete. We need to know what we're working with.

Comment: Plant Biology and Vaccine Development sections are complete, which concludes the Biology and Biotechnology category of the big list. I'll be moving on to the Earth and Space Science category next.

Comment: Astrobiology and Astrophysics sections complete.

Comment: Earth Remote Sensing, Heliophysics, and Near-Earth Space Environment secctions are complete, which concludes the Earth and Space Science category of the big list. Next up is the Educational Activities and Outreach category.

Comment: @uhoh I haven't forgotten this list. I've just had a busy July. I'll be back to it soon!

Comment: Commercial Demonstrations, Cultural Activities, and Educational Competitions sections are complete. Next up is Educational Demonstrations.

Comment: I was going to ping you in July 2018, now I can cross that one off my list of things to do this year.

Comment: "[Next up is the Educational Activities and Outreach category.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22038/how-many-robots-have-been-at-in-or-on-the-iss#comment74198_22039)" and there are the robots floating crawling on the outside of the ISS, and the occasional floating, talking, or robot-shaped robots on the inside. I'll only ping once a year now ;-)