# Rockets with n-engines, for n = 1, 2, 3...

Tags: rockets, booster

The question [Astronomical ABCD…!](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23563/7982) suggests a corollary for SXSE.

I'm looking for one example of a rocket with $n$ first-stage engines, for each $n$ for which you can think of an example for. It should be at least built, or very seriously proposed and investigated at a minimum.

I'll start off with some suggestions, items of recent popularity to get the ball rolling, but you don't have to use them.

- **1** - [Falcon-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_1)
- **9** - [Falcon-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9)

Let's first try without jumping immediately to vehicles with variable strap-on number options, and see how that goes?

Comment: I assume you're talking about first stages of orbital vehicles?

Comment: @JCRM ya, "$n$ first-stage engines" is specified in the question. I'd be surprised if there were any rockets with multi-engined first stages *that were not* intended for orbit!

Comment: ah, it wasn't there when i started to answer the question.

Comment: The Bristol Spaceplanes [Ascender](http://bristolspaceplanes.com/projects/ascender/) is suborbital, but has two engines.

Comment: @uhoh I can name a few actually, the most notable is the Falcon booster intended for use with the in-flight abort test, which has 3 engines. In any case, this question really is too broad, so...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I wish we had a "space-golf" tag in analogy to [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) where we could make puzzlers, community wiki's etc. more on-topic. [This one](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22039/12102) seems to have been well received for example.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto The linked [Astronomical ABCD...!](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23563/7982) question contained 23 out of 26 items already, and only asked for the last three missing letters. That would have been a better strategy here perhaps.

Comment: For the record, the mods there didn't like it there, they just weren't as fast to close it. I don't really think it belongs there, but I don't really have a say of moderation there. I did ask around, and it's pretty universal, this kind of question isn't really a question, and isn't appropriate for the site. It could possibly do for a meta question, but not on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

British, very seriously proposed and investigated (and the Black Arrow orbited a satellite after it was cancelled): $$\begin{array} {r l}
\text{Black Arrow}^1 & \text{1 engine with 8 combustion chambers} \\
\text{Europa}^2 & \text{2 rocket engines} \\
\text{MUSTARD}^3 & \text{3 engines (one in each of the triamese craft)} \\
\text{Interim Hotol}^4 & \text{4 engines} \\
\text{Skylon D1}^5 & \text{6 engines with 12 combustion chambers/nozzles.}^* \\
\hline
\text{The BIS Space Ship (1939)}^6 & \text{168 solid motors}^{**}
\end{array}$$

* two engines per nacelle, two SOMA engines in the tail. All running during the latter parts of the ascent.

** OK, perhaps not *so* seriously

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Arrow
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(rocket)
3. umm...
4. err...
5. https://web.archive.org/web/20160328220308/http://www.reactionengines.co.uk/tech_docs/SKYLON_Users_Manual_Rev_2.1.pdf
6. http://www.bis-space.com/what-we-do/projects/bis-lunar-spaceship

Comment: Supporting links for each please!

Comment: I'll try to fact check and link those two later

Comment: I know of the russian engines with 4 combustion chambers per engine, counting also the 4 vernier chambers there are 8 alltogether. Did the Black Arrow also use 4 main and 4 vernier chambers? Are there other engines with more than 8 chambers per engine?

Comment: no, Black arrow had eight chambers in a cross. Each pair of chambers pivoted together along the axis of the arm of the cross to provide roll, pitch and yaw control.

Comment: I've just asked [Have there been any rockets that run seven engines at the same time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41744/12102)

Answer (score 2):

- 5: [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V), first and second stages.
- 8: [Saturn I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_I), first stage.

Comment: The never built and flown Nova C-8 as well as the Saturn C-8 with 8 engines for first and second stage. There was a study using 14 F-1 engine for first stage, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_(rocket)).

Comment: I've just asked [Have there been any rockets that run seven engines at the same time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41744/12102)