# List of supply chain partners in oneweb satellite production line at Florida?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, satellite-constellation, manufacturing, oneweb

I have listed couple of partners for onewebsatellites supply chain.

1) Sol Aero- Solar panels 
2) Sodern  - Star Trackers 
3) ALTIUS - Grappling fixture for deoribiting 
4) New Space systems - Magnetic torquers 
5) RUAG Space -Satellite Structure and Multi Layer Insulation 
6) Syrlinks - Transceiver for TM,TC and LNA for GPS Receiver.
7) Teledyne - Channelisers in payload, Microwave and mmWave Filter assemblies.
8) MDA- Antenna systems for payload 
9) SpaceTech- Solar Array Deployment mechanism.

Request members to add few more to the list.

**References:** 
https://spacenews.com/after-bankruptcy-onewebs-supply-chain-looking-for-new-ways-to-keep-busy/

https://africanews.space/newspace-systems-meets-products-supply-target-for-oneweb-and-others/amp/

https://solaerotech.com/solaero-to-begin-oneweb-solar-panel-production/

https://www.ruag.com/en/news/ruag-space-key-supplier-constellations

https://www.syrlinks.com/documents/21

https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Teledyne_Wins_OneWeb_Satellite_Supply_Contract/a60772

https://www.aerospace-technology.com/projects/oneweb-satellite-constellation/

https://www.spacetech-i.com/products/mechanisms/sadm-for-airbus-oneweb-satellites

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question asks for a list. What if two people give complementary answers? List-based questions in general do not work well across the StackExchange network.

Comment: though your question may feel reasonable, [list questions generally get closed](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23860/12102) in Stack Exchange sites unless you go to [extraordinary means](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12918/51174) to try to [keep them open](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/227613/51174) (votes are +18 and -14)