# Control Systems of space robots?

Tags: robotics

How the control systems of space robots work? Are they based on Machine learning or conventional control systems techniques? Especially mars Rovers like sojourner

Comment: Which space robots?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - how many space robots are there? I don't think they are referring to robotic arms etc. but semi-autonomous robots, like the rovers, Astrobee, etc. I'm sure there have been quite a few but is it so many that an answer is not possible?

Comment: @StevePemberton why not robotic arms?  Even if you only consider the Mars rovers (post-edit), then there are so many subsystems on each, with each their own control system, that one can impossibly answer this question.

Comment: @Ludo - the question mentioned machine learning so I suspect they are interested in autonomous "thinking" operations, I don't think they are asking what is the control system in a robotic arm that is manually operated. Lander robotics I don't know how autonomous the sample grabbers etc. are, I think they probably have pre-programmed routines and the operator gives it movement values, I don't think they just point to a rock and command "drill a sample there".  Do any of the landers have robots that are making decisions? At the moment I can only think of rovers driving, maybe there are more.

Comment: @StevePemberton Assumptions are dangerous. These are all valid questions (too many for one QA), but the OP should clarify so we can know for sure what they'd like to know.

Comment: @StevePemberton I can think of a dozen or so without even trying. You may have an idea in your head of what a "robot" is, but that doesn't mean everyone, specifically the OP or someone who wants to write an answer, agrees. The original version of the question was about as specific as asking "what kind of engine is in a car?" I don't think it's an undue burden on the OP to add a sentence or two of clarification. Now that they've done so, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Ludo -  I did not make an assumption, I said "I suspect" they are interested in autonomous decision type of operations. I was voicing what I suspect is the intention of the question, I raised this possibility to try and stop the impending closure of the question, which (I suspect) is a question which could have some interesting answers.  I think an assumption might be being made that they are asking for a detailed breakdown on how all robotic devices of all types are controlled.  Even if they did want that, is it  not possible to provide a categorized answer with some examples?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I was asking about robots that have some decision making ability such as rovers, I gave Astrobee as an example although like the Ingenuity helicopter I'm not sure we normally think of autonomous flyers as robots, even though yes the word "robot" can mean a lot of different things including drones and arms.  If I was using the general sense I would not have asked "how many" because obviously there are a large number. Even if the question is about robots of all types in space, is it not possible to provide a list of control types, with a few examples in each type?

Comment: DSP_CS - you mentioned machine learning and "especially mars Rovers like sojourner". Are you asking about all types of robotic operations including manually controlled robotic arms, or are you asking about robotic devices that can operate semi-autonomously using decision making capability?

Comment: @StevePemberton no, it is not practically possible to provide a list of anything that is  used as a control system in anything that someone might possibly consider to be a robot. Hence clarification was needed.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I think what types of engines are in cars is an answerable question, would someone say it's not practical to answer because "there are dozens of car manufacturers and each of them have multiple engines". More likely someone would say "the two main categories are gas and diesel, within gas engines there are different cycle types which use different strategies for valve openings and compression, other differences include the number of cylinders and valves (etc. etc.).  But I guess there are too many robots in space to give a similar overview because the question is now closed.

Comment: @OrganicMarble agreed "it is not practically possible to provide a list of anything that is used as a control system in anything that someone might possibly consider to be a robot". There is was (somewhat herculean) effort to make a much more constrained list [How many robots have been at, in, or on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22038/12102) back in 2018 but I guess "robots in space" is almost an uncountable noun by now.

Comment: @uhoh - the question did not ask for a list of control systems, but how do the control systems work, machine learning etc. I realize "how do they work" is vaguely worded and one interpretation is that they want a detailed list of every control on every robot that has ever been in space. However my impression, but OP has not clarified is they are asking for a general description of the types of controls. I gave a car example, someone asking "how are car engines controlled" is not the same as "list the control systems for every car engine ever made". Is types of controls not possible to answer?

Comment: @StevePemberton my comment was narrowly focussed on only the practicality of making a list. Whether or not the question asks for one is a separate question, one which I have not addressed.

Comment: @uhoh - certainly a challenge to make a list considering all of the different experiments done just on ISS (3000+ according to NASA). And as is being discussed here what to include on a list depends on the definition of a robot. I think over time the terms robot and robotics might get more narrowly defined, subcategorized, or even split as they become ever more pervasive and diverse. Similar to the term astronaut which may eventually be redefined or sub-categorized. And perhaps like the word computer which has been somewhat redefined and sub-categorized over time. Or the word planet.