# What is/was the point of Robonaut 2? Has it accomplished anything?

Tags: iss, robotics

I remember being really interested in the [Robonaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robonaut) project when it was first announced, and thinking how cool it was when it was finally launched to the ISS.  Since then, I've heard little about the project. I happened across TildalWave's [excellent answer here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1530/10129) today and was surprised to learn that it has been *four years* since it was first powered up on the station and over a year since it was fitted with "legs".  Yet besides that update, there seems to be little information available online as to what Robonaut actually **does**.  There's a lot of talk about what it *can* do, but from what I can tell, its accomplishments seem to be:

1. Looking cool
2. Staying boxed up
3. Serving as something to be upgraded in the future for vague purposes

Surely I've missed something.  Is there an actual *plan* for Robonaut 2?  I'd welcome a knowledge bomb to be dropped on my cynicism.

Comment: 4. Allowing the astronauts to play Star Wars by speaking to R2.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I know of to keep up with R2 is by searching the (usually updated daily) [ISS On-orbit Status Reports for "robonaut"](https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/?s=robonaut).  The actual [Robonaut web pages](http://robonaut.jsc.nasa.gov/default.asp), like many NASA sites, are not updated very often.

When I just performed this search, it sounds like some major problems have been encountered in July and August of this year, and may not yet be resolved.

Speculation: some of the lack of news may be because a private company (GM) is involved in funding the project.

Comment: I read that in January 2015 Robonaut was detached from the legs for more testing since the legs failed to work properly.

Comment: The problems in July and August sounded pretty serious.