# Will Astrobee be the second time that an autonomous, mobile robot will use ROS in space?

Tags: iss, robotics, ros

The question [ROS is running on the Robonaut, but is the Robonaut running on the ISS (post 2015)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23075/12102) asks about [Robot Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) or [ROS](http://www.ros.org/about-ros/).

In the Art Technica video [Talking Space and Robots with NASA's Terry Fong](https://video.arstechnica.com/watch/talking-space-and-robots-with-nasa-s-terry-fong)

> NASA's Terry Fong, head of the Intelligent Robotics Group, talks about the agency's autonomous robot efforts and the future of bots in space.

he talks about the three [Astrobee](https://www.nasa.gov/astrobee) free-flying autonomous robots that will go to the ISS. After about `02:25` he says that the Astrobee's use ROS.

Following Robonaut, is this the second time that a mobile, autonomous robot will use ROS in space? (presuming that Robonaut has actually done this) Or has ROS been used in other mobile, autonomous scenarios on the ISS, or elsewhere in space?

Comment: Is the question restricted to usage on the ISS? Or in space?
If it is not restricted, then there are many examples of autonomous mobile robots using ROS :)

Comment: I mean it's an open source robotics solution, well programmed open source solutions that address a fundamental need almost always seek widespread adoption. They only cases where they don't is if they have some form of critical flaw which may be ROS's lack of "real-time" processing.....

Comment: @BlueCoder Space for sure. I've made an edit to make that explicit, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most definitive answer I can find is that ROS's website lists Robonaut2 as the only robot using ROS under the [space](https://robots.ros.org/tags/#space) tag. If this is the case, it would in fact make Astrobee the second time a robot uses ROS in space (assuming nothing else gets launched before Astrobee). I can't find mention of anything else using ROS that currently has a plan to be launched.