# Developing a ROS-based Space Cleaning Robot

Tags: debris, simulation, robotic-missions, removedebris-mission

I am currently developing a space debris cleaning robot based on ROS (Robot Operating System) and I am facing challenges in finding suitable simulation software to create a realistic physical environment for testing and validating the robot's performance，I am reaching out to this community seeking recommendations or suggestions for simulation software that align with my project requirements. Specifically, I am looking for a tool that offers:

Realistic physics simulation: Accurate simulation of space dynamics, gravity, and object interactions, including the effects of microgravity.

ROS integration: Seamless integration with ROS to develop and test ROS-based control algorithms and communication interfaces.

Customizability: The ability to customize the simulation environment, including space conditions, debris characteristics, and robot parameters.

Visualization capabilities: Advanced visualization features to analyze the robot's performance and identify any potential issues.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or directions regarding where I can find relevant resources or literature on this topic. I have been searching for information, but it seems that discussions specifically addressing this aspect are limited.

Comment: There are (at least) a few previous questions about ROS who's answers may contain helpful information: [ROS is running on the Robonaut, but is the Robonaut running on the ISS (post 2015)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23075/12102) and [Will Astrobee be the second time that an autonomous, mobile robot will use ROS in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30165/12102) and perhaps [What is/was the point of Robonaut 2? Has it accomplished anything?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10886/12102)

Comment: And the answer to [How many robots have been at, in, or on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22038/12102) lists quite a large number of robots - though it might be hard to drill down on each one to see if any of them uses ROS.